# How to know what BIOS version to learn?

Tags: interrupt, bios

I've read that every manufacturer can produce his own BIOS ,
where to find a specific BIOS interrupts list , and how to know my PC's BIOS version? 
there's a lot ( IBM , AT&T , ..)
And it's really strange that the only reference is RBIL !
where to read "ALL" interrupts of specific version ?

Comment: why do you want/need to deal with the bios?

Comment: I'm trying to write assembly programs that are not based on the operating system , or say i'm just want to free my self from OSs

Comment: Good luck with that 7;^) do you have or can you download your computers motherboard manual - that should give you a list of it's interrupts (they used to)

Comment: how can I know the motherboard manufacture and identifier without unpacking the computer ?

Comment: read the box it came in :)

Comment: :D
is there any way using software ? (assume i'm on a laptop and lost the manual)

Comment: Undoubtedly there is but its outside of my expertise, good luck

Comment: when your computer starts it tells you information about the bios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most BIOS vendors are compatible with the original IBM PC BIOS source, but that is a convention, not a rule.  Many BIOS vendors will offer their own extended/undocumented BIOS calls.

If you are simply trying to boot, read disk sectors, print characters on the screen, etc, you should be able to manage that without having to know which specific BIOS you are running on.  After all, they must be similar enough for DOS to boot!

If you really want to know what specific BIOS you have, you can look in the BIOS POST or setup screens.  Look for a version or ID string.  Otherwise, you can boot Windows and run the System Information tool, which can tell you.  Otherwise, you can dump the F000 segment to a file and run the "[strings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx)" utility on it.  Again, you probably do not need to know this, because it is irrelevant for 99% of the basic PC operations.

My favorite reference for BIOS and DOS interrupts is the *[Programmer's PC Sourcebook (Second Edition)](https://www.google.com/search?q=Programmer%27s%20PC%20Sourcebook&oq=Programmer%27s%20PC%20Sourcebook&aqs=chrome..69i57.961j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=Programmer%27s%20PC%20Sourcebook%20Second%20Edition).*  It's long out of print, but I think you can still find used copies on Amazon.  There are other books out there, but this is the one on my bookshelf that I have used for the last 10+ years.

If you are adverse to spending money, the [Ralf Brown Interrupt List (RBIL)](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ralf/files.html), seems pretty comprehensive, but I have never used it personally.

Comment: Thank you , the problem in  RBIL is that it contains hundreds of interrupts for bunch of machines and video cards together which make learning every thing in his List time wasting . I just want to have a book or list which if I've read it , I will know every interrupt in the intended machine. But I will focus now on IBM's only , Thanks